# Secure Malware analysis on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, malware

I have read on several sites that Cuckoo is outdated, no longer supported, a dead project etc. Would it be wise for me to install it anyway? I want to have a ransomware analysis lab, where I can freely run ransomware (but I'm a bit afraid that it might escape the virtual environment without a sandbox), but apart from that, I don't really need the additional features of a sandbox in terms of... the dynamic behavioural analysis of malware/ransomware, such as registry key operations/ API calls etc.

Or can I for example install a virtual machine within a virtual machine (so, the host is in such a case Ubuntu and the guest Windows)?